# JavaScript - "invalid assignment left-hand side error" when call "new" to create object

Tags: javascript, canvas, referenceerror

I'm implementing a `Binary Search Tree` algorithm using `Canvas & JavaScript`.

First of all, I create a base class (`Node`) with some attributes and functions. 
I got the following error when implementing the `insertNode()` function: `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side` in the following line: `this = new Node(newNodeData); (line 63)`

Here is my code: http://jsbin.com/ASebuRaz/1/edit?html,output

How to fix this error?

Comment: You cannot assign `this` to something new.  You can't change your own pointer.

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertNode' of null`

Comment: Why are you trying to set `this` to something?

Comment: Guess he did it because he is trying to use `this` as an abstraction of an iterator thinking of it as some C pointer variable

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set `this` to anything. `this` refers to the element you are in, and is therefore unchangeable in whatever current scope you are in.

Perhaps you could set a different variable, perhaps `self`, which is not reserved for anything, to maintain the same scope if you have nested objects